# Import existing source code to GitHub

Tags: git, github

How can I import source code from my computer to my GitHub account?

Comment: I found it easiest to use the GitHub GUI and then point the configuration to the root of your workspace and click the "Find Repostitories On your hard driver" button and it will identify all Git local repos in your workspace and allows importing them individually.  Easy.

Comment: @djangofan Which github GUI are you referring to? Do you have a link to the GUI?

Comment: http://windows.github.com/

Comment: Pete's answer worked great on OS X--no need to use a GUI.

Answer (score 986, accepted):

If you've got local source code you want to add to a new remote new git repository without 'cloning' the remote first, do the following (I often do this - you create your remote empty repository in bitbucket/github, then push up your source)

1. Create the remote repository, and get the URL such as `git@github.com:/youruser/somename.git` or `https://github.com/youruser/somename.git`

   *If your local GIT repo is already set up, skips steps 2 and 3*

   ---
2. Locally, at the root directory of your source, `git init`

   2a. If you initialize the repo with a .gitignore and a README.md you should do a `git pull {url from step 1}` to ensure you don't commit files to source that you want to ignore ;)
3. Locally, add and commit what you want in your initial repo (for everything, `git add .` then  `git commit -m 'initial commit comment'`)

   ---
4. to attach your remote repo with the name 'origin' (like cloning would do)
   `git remote add origin [URL From Step 1]`
5. Execute `git pull origin master` to pull the remote branch so that they are in sync.
6. to push up your master branch (change master to something else for a different branch):
   `git push origin master`

Comment: Worked for me.  I found I needed to run ```git pull origin master``` before the git push. Without it, I got the "because the tip of your current branch is behind" error during the push attempt. Maybe this was because I created the remote repository with a starting Readme.md.

Comment: Get the repo URL for the SSH protocol to be able to commit using your ssh private keys instead of typing a password.

Comment: @yuvilio that's exactly why.  If you create your github repo with a readme.md, you are actually now behind what you're trying to make your origin.

Comment: @Pete: while performing `git push origin master` I'm getting error `Permission denied (public key)`. Why?

Comment: As @Snicolas said, if u use SSH, use git@github.com:youruser/somename.git instead of git://github.com/youruser/somename.git .

Comment: @Mohammad if you are using ssh, then you need to ensure you have your ssh identity set up locally on your operating system.  There will be a tutorial that explains how to do this in the help area of your remote repo host

Comment: GitHub explains this same procedure immediately after you have created a new repo. As already said by @yuvilio, you shouldn't initialize your repository with a README. Instead, go with `touch README.md` on your existing local repo

Comment: fyi: I went ahead and created a README.md and ended up with a .gitignore that didn't merge with my existing one. I had to edit .gitignore to resolve the merge and commit before I could push to origin (it's actually convenient to create the README.md - you don't have to type the description again if I want the README to be meaningful)

Comment: I had to do few additional things..

1) Before push do git pull origin master 2) Normal git push did not work for me, I had to do the following git push --set-upstream origin master and then

Comment: If you want README.md or .gitignore files to be created by GitHub, there's no reason not to do so. Resolving the merge is easy, and it's very convenient to have GitHub add your description, LICENSE file, etc.

Comment: The step "git pull origin master" is not necessary if you created the project in github totally empty (without a readme file)

Comment: I wanted to discard my existing remote changes, so `git push -f origin master`.

Comment: I had to use double quotes for the commit: git commit -m "First Commit"

Comment: @Peter - Any suggestions for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34201058/2404470) please?

Comment: Why do you need to pull twice? Why do you need to do both steps 2a and 5?

Comment: On step 5 there is an error: fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

Answer (score 42):

This is explained in the [excellent free eBook ProGit](http://progit.org/book/ch2-5.html). It assumes you already have a local Git repository and a remote one. To connect them use:

```
$ git remote
origin
$ git remote add pb git://github.com/paulboone/ticgit.git
$ git remote -v
origin    git://github.com/schacon/ticgit.git
pb    git://github.com/paulboone/ticgit.git
```

To push the data from the local repository to GitHub use:

```
$ git push pb master
```

If you have not setup a local and/or a remote repository yet, check out the help on [GitHub](http://help.github.com/creating-a-repo/) and the [previous chapters in the book](http://progit.org/book/).

Answer (score 21):

One of the comments mentioned using the GitHub GUI, but it didn't give any specific help on using and notice that most if not all the answers were useful at the command prompt only.

If you want to use the GitHub GUI, you can follow these steps:

1. Click the "+" button and choose "Add Local Repository"
   [image]
2. Navigate to the directory with your existing code and click the "Add" button.
3. You should now be prompted to "Create a new local Git repository here" so click the "Yes" button.
   [image]
4. Add your "Commit Summary" and "Extended description" as desired. By default, all of your files should selected with checkmarks already. Click the "Commit & Sync" button.
   [image]
5. Now you will be prompted to add the name and description of your project as well as which account to push it to (if you have multiple). Click the "Push Repository" button
   [image]

After a moment with a spinning GitHub icon, your source code will belong to a local repository and pushed/synchronised with a remote repository on your GitHub account. All of this is presuming you've previously set up the GitHub GUI, your GitHub account, and SSH keys.

Comment: @cfont Does this keep the long history that already exists in my local repository, or does it just create one huge commit and I've lost all my history?

Comment: @theJollySin, sorry I need to work on getting my stackoverflow notifications working properly I suppose. This should retain the history of your existing local repository. TBH, I didn't test that out at the time but I cannot think of a reason it would squash your local history. In fact, the whole point should be to retain that unless you actually want to squash the commits.

Answer (score 12):

As JB quite rightly points out, it's made incredibly easy on GitHub by simply following the instructions.

Here's an example of the instructions displayed after setting up a new repository on GitHub using [http://github.com/new](https://github.com/new) when you're logged in.

```
Global setup:

 Set up Git:
  git config --global user.name "Name"
  git config --global user.email email@gmail.com


Next steps:

  mkdir audioscripts
  cd audioscripts
  git init
  touch README
  git add README
  git commit -m 'first commit'
  git remote add origin git@github.com:ktec/audioscripts.git
  git push -u origin master


Existing Git repository?

  cd existing_git_repo
  git remote add origin git@github.com:ktec/audioscripts.git
  git push -u origin master


Importing a Subversion repository?

  Check out the guide for step-by-step instructions.
```

It couldn't be easier!!

Answer (score 10):

Yes. Create a new repository, doing a `git init` in the directory where the source currently exists.

More here: http://help.github.com/creating-a-repo/

Answer (score 8):

I had a bit of trouble with merging when trying to do Pete's steps. These are the steps I ended up with.

1. Use your OS to delete the `.git` folder inside of the project folder that you want to commit. This will give you a clean slate to work with. This is also a good time to make a `.gitignore` file inside the project folder. This can be a copy of the `.gitignore` created when you created the repository on github.com. Doing this copy will avoid deleting it when you update the github.com repository.
2. Open Git Bash and navigate to the folder you just deleted the `.git` folder from.
3. Run `git init`. This sets up a local repository in the folder you're in.
4. Run `git remote add [alias] https://github.com/[gitUserName]/[RepoName].git`. [alias] can be anything you want. The [alias] is meant to tie to the local repository, so the machine name works well for an [alias]. The URL can be found on github.com, along the top ensure that the HTTP button out of HTTP|SSH|Git Read-Only is clicked. The `git://` URL didn't work for me.
5. Run `git pull [alias] master`. This will update your local repository and avoid some merging conflicts.
6. Run `git add .`
7. Run `git commit -m 'first code commit'`
8. Run `git push [alias] master`

Comment: -1 This does a tiny bit more than just "import existing code to github".  it deletes the entire repository history!

Answer (score 6):

1. Open your GitHub dashboard (it's at https://github.com/ if you're logged in)
2. Click on *[New Repository](https://github.com/repositories/new)*
3. Fill in the blanks; click on *Create Repository*
4. Follow instructions on the page that appears then

Answer (score 6):

From Bitbucket:

Push up an existing repository. You already have a Git repository on your computer. Let's push it up to Bitbucket:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/javacat/geo.git
git push -u origin --all   # To push up the repo for the first time
```

Comment: fyi, -u is the same as --set-upstream.

Answer (score 4):

I came here looking for a simple way to add existing source files to a GitHub repository. I saw @Pete's excellently complete answer and thought *"What?! There must be a simpler way."*

Here's that simpler way in five steps (no console action required!)

If you're really in a hurry, you can just read step 3. The others are only there for completeness.

1. Create a repository on the GitHub website. (I won't insult your intelligence by taking you through this step-by-step.)
2. Clone the new repository locally. (You can do this either through the website or through desktop client software.)
3. **Find the newly cloned repository on your hard drive and add files just like you would to a normal directory.**
4. Sync the changes back up to GitHub.
5. That's it!

Done!

Answer (score 4):

Add a GitHub repository as remote origin (replace [] with your URL):

```
git remote add origin [git@github.com:...]
```

Switch to your master branch and copy it to develop branch:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b develop
```

Push your develop branch to the GitHub develop branch (`-f` means force):

```
git push -f origin develop:develop
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, if you opt for creating an empty repo on GitHub it gives you exact instructions that you can almost copy and paste into your terminal which are (at this point in time):

```
…or create a new repository on the command line

echo "# ..." >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some instructions on how to initiate a GitHub repository and then push code you've already created to it. The first set of instructions are directly from GitHub.

Source: https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/

1. In the upper-right corner of any page, click, and then click *New repository*.
2. Create a short, memorable name for your repository. For example, "hello-world".
3. Optionally, add a description of your repository. For example, "My first repository on GitHub."
4. Choose between creating a public or private repository.
5. Initialize this repository with a README.
6. Create repository.

Congratulations! You've successfully created your first repository, and initialized it with a README file.

Now after these steps you will want to push the code on your local computer up to the repository you just created and you do this following these steps:

1. `git init` (in the root folder where your code is located)
2. `git add -A` (this will add all the files and folders in your directory to be committed)
3. `git commit -am "First Project commit"`
4. `git remote add origin git@github.com:YourGithubName/your-repo-name.git` (you'll find this address on the GitHub repository you just created under "ssh clone URL" on the main page)
5. `git push -u origin master`

That's it. Your code will now be pushed up to GitHub. Now every time you want to keep pushing code that has changed just do.

1. `git commit -m "New changes"`
2. `git push origin master` (if master is the branch you are working on)

Answer (score 1):

Solution for me:

The problem is the size of a file, which cannot exceed 100M.

Before migrating to github, in the repository do this:

```
git clone --mirror git://example.com/some-big-repo.git

wget http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/madgag/bfg/1.12.12/bfg-1.12.12.jar

mv bfg-1.12.12.jar bfg.jar

java -jar bfg.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M some-big-repo.git

cd some-big-repo.git

git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive

git push
```

Ready!

Now make the migration again by the tool: https://github.com/new/import

see more:
[Error while pushing to github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227851/error-while-pushing-to-github-repo)
and
https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

I hope I helped you.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Create your repository in git hub

Allow to track your project by GIT

1. using CMD go to folder where your project file is kept->cd /automation/xyz/codebase
   check for git intialization with command git status
   If you get this error message: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git, that means the folder you are currently in is not being tracked by git. In that case, initialize git inside your project folder by typing git init, then going through the process of adding and committing your project.

If you get another error message, read carefully what it says. Is it saying git isn't installed on your computer by saying that the word 'git' is not recognized? Is it saying that you're already in a folder or sub-folder where git is initialized? Google your error and/or output to understand it, and to figure out how to fix it.

now run following command

#

echo "your git hub repository name" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://

#

above block you will get when first time you are opening your repository

If error occurs or nothing happens after last command run"git push -u origin master"
dont worry

go to folder where code is available and through git extention push it to git [URL], branch