# How to push existing source code to a repository in github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku, github

I have a rails app hosted on heroku and i want to push the code to github(Aready created a repo on there).I tried to follow the steps in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658606/import-existing-source-code-to-github) .Since i already have a local repository and currently can push and pull from heroku  i skipped step 2 and 3 .But when i do step 4

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:sparkz19/stark-journey-1727.git
```

It says

```
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

And when i do `git remote -v` 
It says

```
    origin  git@heroku.com:stark-journey-1727.git (fetch)

    origin  git@heroku.com:stark-journey-1727.git (push)
```

What do i need to do here?Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git complains because origin is already defined. If you still want to keep the heroku remote you could use git remote rename to save it as another remote:

```
git remote rename origin heroku
```

Reset the url with git remote set-url:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:sparkz19/stark-journey-1727.git
```

Now you can push and pull to any you like:

```
git pull heroku master
git push origin master
```

Comment: i still want to be able to push and pull from heroku though .What will the first command actually do?

Comment: No, the first command will overwrite current origin url (heroku) with the url to github. Do both. Rewrote my answer a bit to simplify.

Comment: In that case i wont be able to pull and push from heroku?

Comment: Thank you.But now it wont let me push to git `Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again`and i am afraid to pull because it might override my project.What do i do here?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Add it as a new question instead so we can go through it properly.

Answer (score 2):

Just give your new remote a different name than `origin` and you'll be good to go.