# Updating a Git repository

Tags: git, github

What is the proper terminal command to update a GitHub repository whose files are stored locally on my Mac machine?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658606/import-existing-source-code-to-github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git push <remote> <branch>`. For example:

```
git push -u origin master
```

If you haven't yet set up a remote, add one using `git remote add <name> <uri>`. For example:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/example.git
```

Comment: I'm getting this response when using git remote add origin <name> "Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git" even though I have successfully pushed code to a repo..

Comment: @Derek: Are you in `.git`? Try `cd`ing to the parent folder before using `remote add`. (And I'm not quite sure how to answer that first question... `:D`)

Comment: perfect, there we go. Thanks so much for your help. And yea, no need to answer the first question :)

Comment: hey sorry to bother you but I actually just tried this command and it doesn't seem to update my files correctly on the repo even though it produces this response: Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Everything up-to-date