# Load pre-existing directories as separate branches on github?

Tags: git, github

I am just getting started with github and I currently have a directory that I had previously been manually syncing with two other directories on different machines. All of the directories have the same name. Is is possible to create a main branch on github and then load each of the different directories as separate branches? All three directories basically have the same material. They are all similar enough and accomplish the same goals on their respective platforms that I would like to keep them logically under one main branch.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a simpler approach but i would do this:

1. Create a github repo and import your sources from one of your directories as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658606/import-existing-source-code-to-github)
2. On your other machines clone into a new directory with `git clone git://github.com/youruser/somename.git newdir`
3. Create a new branch in your `newdir` with `git checkout -b branch-b origin/master`
4. Copy all files from your source directory into `newdir`
5. Add, commit and push:

   ```
   git add .
   git commit -m 'Changes from Branch B'
   git push origin branch-b
   ```