# How do I configure Eclipse to use an existing git repository with existing source code?

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I have Eclipse Juno with EGit and a project that I've been working on for a while. I've decided to move it to Git, so I created a Github account and downloaded and installed the program. The repository is at `C:\Users\username\GitHub\project_name\`, but all it has is the `README.md` file.

How can I configure Eclipse to use my existing source code (in a workspace separate from the git folder) to work well with git? I've tried using **Window** → **Show View** → **Other** and selecting "Git Repositories," but other than adding a repository (which I have done) I can't figure out how to sync the code.

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658606/import-existing-source-code-to-github) but I get the impression that those answers will perform a one-time commit, instead of a sync.

---

**To clarify:** The repository does not have any code. I would like my existing code (in the Eclipse workspace) to be synced to the new repository.

Comment: Git != github. Just point Eclipse at the existing git repo. The empty repo with the readme is useless to you.

Comment: That's my question - how do I point it there and have it sync my code?

Comment: Sounds like "in a workspace separate from the git folder" is the problem. Why isn't the folder containing the code part of the workspace?

Comment: @MattBall: The workspace contains the code. The git repository is separate from the two. How can I make the repository basically point to the workspace?

Comment: You don't. You turn the workspace (or one of its subdirectories) _into_ a repository with [`git init`](http://gitref.org/creating/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you already have a git repository in place, first copy all your files to that directory (yes, manually) and do a `git commit -a` to commit all the files into the repository. I'm assuming here that you've already initialized the repository at `C:\Users\username\GitHub\project_name\` with `git init`.

In eclipse, go to **File** → **Switch Workspace** → **Other...** and point it to a workspace of your choice that can be completely different than the location of your code, or your earlier workspace. In fact, don't point it to the directory which contains your git repository.

Once you have a clean workspace, go to **File** → **New** → **Other...**, select **Git** → **Git Repository** and enter the path of your git repository (`C:\Users\username\GitHub\project_name\`). Enter a name for the repository, and click **Finish**.

I would really recommend you read at least the first few chapters of the [git book](http://git-scm.com/book) to understand how git works, and to help you push and pull code to and from remote repositories.

If your existing repository is not git, you're going to have a hard time keeping the directories in sync. You might want to setup [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/) to sync the directories. There is no way AFAIK for eclipse to automagically keep the two repositories in sync.