# Source code gone after trying to upload it to a repo

Tags: git, repository

I have followed 1st answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658606/import-existing-source-code-to-github) question to upload my source code to my repo but my files got deleted. Now there is only a README.md file and .git folder

Can I recover those files?

EDIT: I just realized, I forgot to do `git commit -m 'initial commit comment'` and only did
`git add .`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just realized, I forgot to do `git commit -m 'initial commit comment'` and only did `git add .`

Then the git pull probably re-initialized the working tree to the remote content (hence the `README.md`)

You can try and recover your files from the index by following "[Recover files that were added to the index but then removed by a git reset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10783950/6309)":

- make a full backup of your current repo
- try a `git fsck --full --unreachable --no-reflog`