# Elastic Beanstalk, Git and AWS Tools: How to clone repository to another workstation

Tags: git, version-control, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just discovered the amazing possibilities of AWS.
So here is what I did yesterday:

```
- I have created an EB stack (PHP)
- Created a git repository on my workstation 
- Downloaded AWS tools for windows, 
- Did eb.init (the AWS config stuff)
- Wrote some code
- Finally git committed and aws.push-ed it to my EB stack
```

Everything ok.
But now today I am working at another workstation and want to continue my project. How can i do a git clone now? I want to download all the files to this workstation, commit some stuff and finally aws.push it to my EB stack?

First of all I downloaded AWS tools to this workstation, created a new folder in which I did git init but what is the url for git clone? And how do i get the EB settings? I tried to do a eb init but that leads me to the generation of a new stack and doesn't provide any option to download my existing files.

I am using windows (powershell, putty, ...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, congratulations on your first push to Elastic Beanstalk!

Now, about repositories. There are few options for you to continue your work on the second workstation, all depends on your future needs:

- Copy entire project directory from "workstation A" to "workstation B". Acceptable if you are going to continue to work on "workstation B" from now on.
- Clone git project from "workstation A" to "workstation B". You will have origin on "workstation A" and can push your commits there. Not really flexible, if you have to move to "workstation C" later.

> > $ cd my-projects-on-workstation-b
> >
> > $ git clone path-to-my-project-on-workstation-a/myproject.git

- Push your entire project to a shared location online. The best option.

I prefer [bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org) for my private projects (unlimited private repositories) and [github.com](https://github.com) for open source projects.

Instructions for BitBucket: [Import code from an existing project](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Import+code+from+an+existing+project)

Instructions for GitHub: [Import existing source code to github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658606/import-existing-source-code-to-github)

Comment: To clarify, Elastic Beanstalk is _not a git repository_. Elastic Beanstalk is push-only. It has a git interface for accepting deployments, but isn't an actual repository. You'll need to solve that with other options (e.g., GitHub, BitBucket).

Comment: @RyanParman I believe that neither question nor answer implied that Elastic Beanstalk can be used as a repository. :-) Again, anyone can be perfectly fine with two workstations, GitHub or BitBucket are here for the convenience - you don't have to worry that the workstation is on or off, for example.

Comment: Ah that's the point. I thought I could use EB as repository (btw., why isn't that possible?). One workstation is at my home (turned off during the day) and the other one is at my workplace (turned off ober the night). So I will use bitbucket in the future, that problem is solved. But what is not solved: After I cloned the repository to my second workstation, how can I perform an aws.push from there? Do I need to copy the .elasticbeanstalk folder from the first workstation, is that the only possible way?

Comment: @user3082009 After cloning repo to your second workstation, perform `eb init` for the project. Give the same answers. `.elasticbeanstalk` contains workstation specific metadata, I would not copy that.

Comment: Ok thank you. I thought performing eb init again would create another EB container. AWS documentation is very bad at this point.

Comment: @user3082009 Just make sure you use the same name for the application and environment. AWS is constantly working on the tools and the documentation, even if sometimes it's lacking, I'm sure that it will be improved in the future.

Comment: @Andrey Myatlyuk: Having worked on parts of the Elastic Beanstalk experience, I've seen plenty of confusion because users thought that EB's "git support" meant "git repository". I read between the lines and guessed that this was what user3082009 was having issues with. :)

Comment: @RyanParman: I can see it now :-) Thank you for your help in answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

Elastic beanstalk is **NOT a git repository.**

Coming from Heroku I expected it will be, but it's not.

**it's a one way push.**

Make sure you work through github (Or Bitbucket)