# Difference between cloning a directory and cloning a git file

Tags: git

What is the difference between the following two commands?

```
1. git clone https://github.com/kotlin-hands-on/intro-coroutines
2. git clone https://github.com/kotlin-hands-on/intro-coroutines.git
```

I used the above two commands in different directories and compared the results. There were differences in some binary files in the .git directories, so that means that those two commands do something different, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: There’s no difference on GitHub – both URLs refer to the same repo. The meanings of HTTP paths are up to the individual Git server, though, so the same might not be true of non-GitHub services (but for most popular alternatives, it is). Any differences you see are either going to be the verbatim origin URL being stored or typical noise like timestamps/nondeterministic values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git does not require a .git extension when cloning from GitHub. Is this a feature of Git or of GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49185530/git-does-not-require-a-git-extension-when-cloning-from-github-is-this-a-featur)