# What are the git commands to sync a Visual Studio Code project to Github

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I have a project in VS Code. I want to have it automatically synced with my Github. How can I accomplish this with a series of `git` commands from the command line?

I think the first one is

```
git init
```

but that does not fully accomplish the job. What are the other commands I need to do?

Comment: How *would* it fully accomplish the job? At the very least you need to create and target an appropriate remote; see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4658606/3001761, https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-new-repository/. It's unclear what you mean by *"automatically synced"*, too; you'll still have to make and push commits.

Answer (score 3):

`git init` will initialize a new **local** git repository in your project folder.
If you have a **remote** repository (at GitHub) and want to work with its content in your computer, you have to use the command `git clone <url_of_the_github_repository_extension_dot_git>`.

ie: `git clone https://github.com/username/repo_name.git`

After clone the **remote** repository into your computer, you will have a **local** repository connected with the **remote** cloned repository and then you can start to change the **local** repository and push your changes to the **remote** repository.

To save your changes in you **local** repository you can use the script below:

```
git add .
git commit -m "a message to describe your commit"
```

To send the changes saved **locally** to your **remote** repository you need to execute the command below:

```
git push origin master
```

This is the simplest flow to work with a remote GitHub repo in your computer.