# Pushing a project in local file system to Github

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am a bit curious about pushing a locally created folder(project) to Github. Is it possible? 
Please let me explain what I have already done.
I am using Git for Windows on Windows 8.1 64-bit.

1. Created a new project using init command in the Git local root i.e. projects. Please refer the bash commands and messages below.

**$ git init fresh-project**
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/MyDev/projects/fresh-project/.git/

2.

**$ ls**
fresh-project/

3. `**$ cd fresh-project**`
4. `**ls**`
5. ```
   **$ git status**
   ```

   On branch master

   No commits yet

   nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
6. ```
   **Used $ code hipster.txt**
   ```

   To create the file by opening VSCode and added some text.
7. ```
   **$ git status**
   ```

   On branch master

   No commits yet

   Untracked files:
     (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
           hipster.txt

   nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
8. `**$ git add hipster.txt**`
9. ```
   **$ git status**
   ```

   On branch master

   No commits yet

   Changes to be committed:
     (use "git rm --cached ..." to unstage)
           new file:   hipster.txt
10. ```
    **$ git commit**
    ```

    hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...
    [main 2020-04-12T09:45:20.658Z] update#setState idle
    [main 2020-04-12T09:45:50.660Z] update#setState checking for updates
    [main 2020-04-12T09:45:50.870Z] update#setState idle
    [master (root-commit) b427f7c] Adding new file with hipster ipsum This was done with VSCode in 12th April 2020 15:20
     1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
     create mode 100644 hipster.txt

11.

**$ git status**
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

```
After the 11th step I want to push the whole local repository to Github.com. I haven't created a 
repository in Github with the name of 'fresh-project'.

What else do I have to do to make this to happen?
```

Thanks and regards,
Chiranthaka

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import existing source code to GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658606/import-existing-source-code-to-github)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have searched on github for this.
It's easy all you need to do is first add files and commit then add remote repo url and push to github

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/user/yourremoterepo.git
```

If you want to create repo using command line you need to use Github api for that
You need an access token and curl to POST repo

```
curl -H "Authorization: token ACCESS_TOKEN" --data '{"name":"Reponame"}' https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

Comment: Thanks @Bibek but I already used the command once like this way
$ git remote add origin https://github/chiranthakaj/fresh-project.git

I got the error like the below

fatal: remote origin already exists.

But when I refresh the repo in Github all repo view I can't see the 'fresh-project' repository.

Comment: please refer the image in the link
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Hat-qs6932nSI19cJ6BFhX4Omkcmx32X

Comment: I guess you haven't created fresh-project repo for that. First create a repo on github then gitinit your local project and add remote origin and then you can push your code

Comment: Remember you cannot add origiin without initializing repository on github either manually or by API

Comment: Thanks @Bibek for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, when you create a new repository on Github, it displays steps on how you push an existing local project/repository from command line:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/yourremoterepo.git
git push -u origin master
```

Furthermore, you can also use -v as below to showcase the URLs git has stored to be used for reading/writing to that remote repo:

```
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/username/yourremoterepo (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/username/yourremoterepo (push)
```

If this isn't pointing to your required project (fresh-project), there's a high likelihood that the project was never created on Github. Or the steps to create the remote weren't followed correctly.

Assuming you're a beginner to git as myself, I would recommend to start reading the Pro-git book. It can be found [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).
For reference on working with remotes, see [section 2.5](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)